# Expected object or value

Tags: surveymonkey

I have setup a developer account and created a access token as described in the docs using "custom application" and providing key, id and secret in the console.

Requests made via the console such as `get_survey_list` work fine.

However if I try any other http client like curl I get this:

```
{"status":3,"errmsg":"Expected object or value"}
```

The curl code is:

```
curl -H 'Authorization:bearer xxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=xxx --data-binary ''
```

I have tried other methods (httpclient, poster, in my appliction) I always get this result.
My request looks absolutely identical to the request data that is shown in the console output.

The only request that works is `user/get_user_details`.

Can anybody help?
Thanks Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request certain data fields with the `--data-binary` flag. For example, if I want:

```
"title","analysis_url","date_created","date_modified"
```

my curl statement looks like this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization:bearer xxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=xxx --data-binary '{"fields":["title","analysis_url","date_created","date_modified"]}'
```

*(please replace XXX with your authenticate parameters)*

Read more details [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list) - the page also includes a full example of the curl statement:

```
curl -H 'Authorization:bearer XXXYYYZZZ' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list/?api_key=your_api_key --data-binary '{"fields":["title","analysis_url","date_created","date_modified"], "start_date":"2013-02-02 00:00:00", "end_date":"2013-04-12 22:43:01", "order_asc":false, "title":"test3"}'
```

Comment: cool thx. that worked.
I dont see this in the documentation though. Here https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list it is stated that fields among all other params are optional.

Comment: Good point. The SM dev team is active here, so I'm sure they can clarify.

Comment: I guess without any fields, you still need --data-binary '{"fields":[]}'

Comment: You need to provide it with at least an empty json dictionary - e.g. '{}'

Answer (score 0):

`get_survey_details` can be called with no parameters, but it still requires a valid JSON object to be POSTed. As Miles commented, a simple empty JSON object will suffice: `{}`

The error message you got, "Expected object or value", indicates that no JSON object could be decoded from the POST data.